# interacting with a container view in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, segue, uicontainerview

I have a project with 3 view controllers.

ViewController has 2 buttons ("Load A" and "Load B"), a label displaying "A is loaded" and a container View.

The Container view has a view controller called ViewA. With a  button (Update Label)

There is also an unattached View called ViewB. With a button (Update Label)

When ViewController loads it embeds ViewA in the container, I want to be able to press 'Load B' and have ViewB load into the container (Without using hidden) and then press "Update Label" in ViewB and have the label in ViewController refresh with "B is loaded".

I've been searching for some time but cannot seem to find a solution written in swift. 
How can I segue within the container and have one view controller trigger a refresh in another?

EDIT:

[image: storyboard]

ViewController A Embeds in the container in ViewDidLoad.
I want to replace it with ViewControllerB upon a button press.
And from within the container reach back to the main view and update the label to "ViewControllerB is Loaded" by pressing the "Update Label" Buton in ViewController B.

Comment: OK I'll show you,with screenshots

Comment: Thanks Stefan, but not quite what I was looking for, I've edited my question to make it more clear. and added a screenshot.

My Issue is all to do with loading into and reaching out from the container view UI Element.

Comment: You can put load b on a,and make a segue.I'm looking to see how you can do it from the loadb button

Comment: Oddly putting a segue from a to b causes the main view to be replaced with b rather then loading it into the container.

Comment: a sec,I'm looking,how to do it

Comment: Nope,containerView can only contain only one view,there is no segue .Try tabviewcontroller

Comment: I don't really understand the Objective-C code, but is something like this possible in swift?.  [storyboards with custom container view controllers](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers)

Comment: Yes,if you can translate the code,but it shows how to do it,so you don't need to tranlate the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did end up finding a solution that worked for me.

You can segue within the container view by embedding a tab view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Control drag from the button to the new view Controller,this is what you are gonna see[image]
Now we need to create a class for our new view contorller[image]
Make sure it is of type UIViewController[image]
Now make sure you set up your view controller from the identity inspector[image]
Now just do the actions and outlets.In the class that you created[image]
Do the same for the BViewController
Or put a button that segues to the BViewController and do the same